# Autofilter then select range below specific cell and select visible cells and delete entire row

Tags: excel, vba

*I have been trying to write this code but when I run the code it displays Application-defined or object-defined error in the line

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Rng).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

Please help with the error I have made

```
Dim xLastRow As Long
Dim xLstRw As Long
Dim Rng2 As Range, Rng As Range
Set xLstRw = Cells(Row.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng2 = Range("J7")
Set Rng = Rng2.Offset(1, xLstRw)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets(Worksheets("Home").Range("I10").Value).Activate
Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Insert
With Application.ActiveSheet
xLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A7:A" & xLastRow).Value = Worksheets("Home").Range("I9").Value
Range("A7").EntireRow.Insert
ActiveSheet.Range("A7:T" & xLastRow).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="="
ActiveSheet.Range(Rng).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: First of all, why are you using `.Select`?

Comment: @braX ........... Thanks for your reply I have changed the code line to 

ActiveSheet.Range(Rng).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

But still, the error continues to appear

Comment: Without knowing what the value of `xLastRow` i'll just point out the obvious. You are using a variable named with "row" in the name in the place of a "column" value - here is the definition of `Offset` - `Property Offset([RowOffset], [ColumnOffset]) As Range`

Comment: Got the correction done it worked but now shows Compile error: Object Required" I have also edited to revised code in the above query

Comment: It tells you where the problem is... `Set xLstRw = Cells(Row.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` - `Row.Count` - There is no variable called `Row` with a property called `Count` - maybe you meant `Rows`?